# struts 2 - action class is not mapped

Tags: struts2

I am starting to study struts 2. I followed the example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_examples.htm).

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package extends="struts-default">
      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>HelloWorld3</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloWorldAction.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

public class HelloWorldAction{
   private String name;

   public String execute() throws Exception {
      return "success";
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

But after running and submitting the form, 404 error occurs.

`type: Status report`

`message: /HelloWorld3/hello`

`description:The requested resource (/HelloWorld3/hello) is not available.`

It does not produce any error in the console. I think the action class is not getting mapped. I know this kind of error is common to all struts beginners but I swear I've been googling this since yesterday.

struts.xml is inside /src/, I also tried putting it inside WEB-INF/classes, still got no luck.

I'm using eclipse gallileo and tomcat 6 inside it.

Replies are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your class could extend ActionSupport class or Action Interface then only it will become an action class. And no need call the method execute explicitly by default it will call execute method. If you were overriding it you need to mention that method name.

And it's not mandatory to use ActionSupport class. This is basically a helper class which provides many out of the box features for you, but at same time Struts2 framework do not ask to use this class, all it want is an entry method for your action class with return type as String and which can throw a general Exception

**beside validation or Internationalization this class also provides many other features like Action level Errors etc.**

```
<action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction">


    package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

    public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport{
       private String name;

       public String execute() throws Exception {
          return "success";
       }

       public String getName() {
          return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you keep your HelloWorld.jsp? Put your HelloWorld.jsp webcontent folder and try it.

Comment: HelloWorld.jsp and index.jsp are inside WebContent folder.

Comment: First of all you need to figure out whether your request going to hello action or not. Put some sop and make sure that it's going to your action.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is sop? And in what way can I figure out whether my request is going to hello action?

Comment: System.out.println("I'm in hello world"); common on dude :P

Comment: Ah ok. But how can it happen when struts is not even directing request to the action class (that is what I think)? As what I have mentioned 404 error occurs after submitting the form from index.jsp. Anyway I tried doing sop, haven't seen the soped message in the console.

Comment: As per my understanding it's going to your action but unable to find result jsp page

Comment: If it is really going to the action class then it should have printed a message in the console since I've put an sop in its execute method. Also, the result page which is HelloWorld.jsp is inside WebContent folder.

Comment: how you are hitting the your action post url?

Comment: I already solved it. Please see my answer. Thank you for helping appreciated it a lot.

Comment: The first line of your answer is incorrect. Actions are not required to implement the `Action` interface or extend `ActionSupport`.

Comment: @StevenBenitez Which Struts2 version you were using?

Comment: @StevenBenitez You are correct i was updated my answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, just realized the `web.xml` is not the same with the `web.xml` in the tutorial. Also I forgot to specify the package name in `struts.xml`. After correcting these, I then encountered an error in the console,

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils`

To solve this problem I added `commons-lang3-x.y` in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory together with other jars required by the tutorial to be added.

Answer (score 0):

add `commons-lang3.x.y.z jar` and `commons-fileupload-x.y.z jar` to your `buildpath` to avoid `'resource not available'` error

Answer (score 0):

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/

You can get the Simple Struts 2 Example Demo with the jar files.